# How should text be handled in responsive design?

Tags: responsive-design

For websites and applications alike

- Should you let text take a certain % of width?
- Base it off the user's screen resolution?
- Based on window width/height?

Comment: Unclear question!

Comment: @Alaa Mh I realized that now, whoops. Should I edit or post new question, properly phrased?

Comment: just edit it and make sure to explain your issue clearly and to put the expected result also what you have done so far